# setContentView(R.layout.main); error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
package com.elfapp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button btn_Login;
    private EditText et_UserName;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btn_Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login);
        btn_Login.setOnClickListener(this);

        et_UserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_userName);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.equals(btn_Login)) {
                // skriver ut en toast när man klickar på knappen
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ansluter till server...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // används i debuggern för att påvisa att programmet exekverat hit
            Log.v("ThisApp", "onClick Successful");

                // TODO skickar det som står i et_UserName till controller (genom TCP/IP), som ska kolla om användaren finns
            // send et_UserName.getText().toString() to controller

                // if(username exists)
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RoomActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

I'm getting an error on the line containing `setContentView(R.layout.main);`
Not sure about what the error/exception is because I'm not used to working in Eclipse..

Comment: Yep, it's in res/layout/ and I even made sure it's saved and updated by ctrl+S

Comment: Click Window-Show View - Onther-Android-Logcat(Lagcat tab will appear) and watch your errors there.

Comment: Seems you don't have runtime error, my previous comment wont help;) Anyway, there is Promblems tab in Eclipse, look there.

Comment: could you elaborate on where it is located?

Comment: So I've checked the LogCat log, I can dump it, where do you want it dumped (f.e. pastebin), and what layer of the log? (verbose, debug, info, warn, error)?

Comment: Is there anything in particular that I should be looking for in the log? I'm not used to debugging Android apps with LogCat, only debugging Java applications with the debugger in NetBeans..

Comment: First of all, if your app can't be run(and I think it can't) then there is nothing you can find in Logcat. Watch Problems tab instead.

Comment: Ok, the Problem tab is in the Java perspective, not in the Debug perspective.. that's what I missed..
So my errors are:
id cannot be resolved or is not a field Main.java;

layout cannot be resolved or is not a field;

ViewerConnector cannot be resolved to a type;

ViewerConnector cannot be resolved to a type;

Comment: do you have main.xml in res/layout/ and do you have the ids you are using for findViewById defined in that layout?

Comment: Yes, the program is starting, but it crashes when I click on the button, (the statements below:
public void onClick(View v) {

Comment: The Problems tab show me 0 errors but 38 warnings, the app crashes when I click on the button.

Comment: If the app runs and crashes when you click the button, then you do want to look in the logcat view.  Near the bottom there should be an exception trace in red.  Looking at your code, my guess is that you haven't added RoomActivity to your AndroidManifest.xml.  Without the log though, that's just a guess.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just take 2 steps and problem would be more likely to get solved:

**Step 1:**
Clean your project by clicking Project -> Clean.

**Step 2:**
Rebuild your project by clicking Project -> Build All.

Also make sure that your layout xml files are syntax error free and you don't have any image which has non-acceptable names (such as a "-" between image name).

Also I request you to have a look at problems window and let me know what errors are being shown there.

Answer (score 17):

This just happend to me a minute ago, but after researching a while, and read this post I notice this.

There is a custom R class with you app name, so when you try to import the missing class (in Eclipse, press Ctrl + Shift + O to import missing classes (Cmd + Shift + O on Mac)), you should see two posible classes the normal:

```
import android.R;
```

And a custom class with your project namespace:

```
import com.yourname.yourapp.R;
```

If you choose the custom class, problem solved!

Answer (score 5):

Using NetBeans 7.0:

If you fix imports before R.java has been generated for your project (before building it the first time) it will add the line:

```
import android.R;
```

which will override the local R.java that you are trying to reference.

Deleting that line resolved the errors for me.

Comment: same issue in IntelliJ 11.0.1. The solution is delete import android.R; as well.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 :
        import android.*;

Step 2 : 
        clean your project

Step 3 :
        Enjoy !!!

Comment: Yeah changing it from android.R; → android.*; fixed it, then right click on Project at Left pane and do 'Clean and Build'. This is with Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

if you have multiple packages with different classes then it will be confusing: try this:

import package_name_from_AndroidManifest.R;

Answer (score 0):

is this already solved?

i also had this problem. I solved it just by cleaning the project.

Project>Clean>Clean projects selected below>Check [your project's name]

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually happen if eclipse accidentally compile the main.xml incorrectly.
The easiest solution is to delete R.java inside gen directory.
Once we delete, than eclipse will generate the new R.java base on the latest main.xml

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

1. Right click on your project.
2. Go to properties.
3. Select android (second option in the Left panel).
4. Click "add..." (in library), select your project.
5. Click ok.
6. And finally, clean your project.

If this doesn't work, make sure that "`android-support-v7-appcompat`" is in your Project Explorer.

If it isn't there, you can add it by importing a simple project from: `C:/android-sdks\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat`

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. Bragging is, too.

Answer (score 0):

use code : setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); instead ofsetContentView(R.layout.main);